# hibernate_sequence creates duplicate key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

A previously working Spring-Boot application came up with a bug.  It last worked 100%.  I made zero changes to the code.  It seems duplicate primary keys are being entered on the hibernate_sequence table.

Worked for three hours today with my mentor developer.  We are both stumped.  We've tried using a different database, renaming and launching a back up of the app.  Have tried different ways to generate ids on the Entities.  We updated Spring-Boot to most current version.  Each time we drop/delete the hibernate_sequence table, you can see in the console when it is generated on initial app start up, you get `Hibernate: insert into hibernate_sequence values (1)` twice.  At this point, since the code has not changed and it worked fine last Wednesday, my mentor feels it might be an update somewhere we are not aware of?

Github Repo of working code : https://github.com/chrisyoung0101/DrinkWithWineApp

IMG 1 : database before hibernate_sequence is generated
                                                                      / IMG 2 : console on app start up /
IMG 3 : database before hibernate_sequence is generated

Errors after trying to save to Pairing table in MySQL :

```
2019-05-19 18:33:23.698  WARN 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2019-05-19 18:33:23.698 ERROR 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
2019-05-19 18:33:23.702 ERROR 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
2019-05-19 18:33:23.717 ERROR 4405 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

[image: MySQL BEFORE hibernate_sequence table generated]
[image: console showing duplicate entries of key 'PRIMARY']
[image: MySQL AFTER hibernate_sequence table generated]

Comment: In your code there is no configuration/actual code that could cause hibernate to generate a table with that name. At least I can't find it

Comment: Thank you for looking at the code.  Still not sure why hibernate is generating the hibernate_sequence table.  A friend suggested that I just truncate the Pairing table and wow!  it worked.  App fully functional once again...